# How do I determine what stats a horse will have at bonding level 4?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

[image]
I can’t see the potential bonding level 4 horse stat. I would like to know if there is a way I can see what stats a horse is going to get after I bond with it so I can determine what breed of horse I want.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.ign.com/wikis/red-dead-redemption-2/Missouri_Fox_Trotter) article on IGN, level 4 bonding:

> can increase your horses base speed by 3 points, and acceleration by 2 points, as well as increasing health and stamina.

It doesn't state how much health and stamina are increased by, but I guess a similar amount.

Click around that article to see which horses have the best base scores.